# When hash(#) link pressed in some websites, does not add hash to url?

Tags: html, hyperlink

I have hash(#) links in my own website, and I realised that when I click on them, a hash sign will always appear at the end of my url. But in other web pages that I was fiddling around with, no matter how many times I clicked the link which had a source of '#', it would never add a hash to the end of my URL. Why is this?

Comment: Do they have javascript which removes the default link behaviour?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They probably have javascript attached to the link that prevents the link action from starting.

A simple

```
return false;
```

will do this

Answer (score 1):

It's normal behaviour of anchor links. If you click link with href like `something#anchor`, you are redirected to url `something` (if you aren't already on it) and `#anchor` appended to url. This anchor refers to some part of page. Single "#" sign is simply the empty anchor.

To avoid this sign appearing in url, you should remove `href` attribute entirely (but sometimes after this action you need to fix stylesheet because appearance of links depends on href attribute presence). Or, if you are using javascript handlers of click event, you should change them to return false.