# How to link to navtab in bootstrap?

Tags: hyperlink, tabs, nav

I have a series of tabs i have created using `navtabs` in bootstrap. I was wondering is it possible to link (hyperlink) directly to one tab?
For example `<a href="page.html#tab1">link to tab 1</a>`

Thanks.

Comment: After a bit of research, it appears that bootstrap.js controls the behaviour of the tabs. Removing this causes the #tab to appear in the url but the tabs no longer work. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10264184/when-hash-link-pressed-in-some-websites-does-not-add-hash-to-url?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>var tabs$ = $(".nav-tabs a");

$( window ).on("hashchange", function() {
    var hash = window.location.hash, // get current hash
        menu_item$ = tabs$.filter("[href=" + hash + "]"); // get the menu element

    menu_item$.tab("show"); // call bootstrap to show the tab
}).trigger("hashchange");</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this javascript

```
var url = document.location.toString();
if (url.match('#')) {
    $('.nav-tabs a[href=#'+url.split('#')[1]+']').tab('show') ;
}
```

Comment: No joy. I should say it's a php document, so I tried echo'ing your code with `'script' tags. Thanks.